# server connection thread too late than onCreate

Tags: java, android, web, server

I'm making app which get server data from mvc spring server.
If client login success in main Activity, app try to get data from server, and use list view show data in next activity.
It works clear in first login, but when I turn back on main Activity, and try login again, next activity doesn't show anything.
I used logs to find problem and I found that when client login again, next activity's `onCreate()` and `onResume()` works too fast. My app uses thread and get data from server, logs says after `onCreate` and `onResume` works and my thread get data from server.

So this is my problem

1 App uses thread to get data from server

2 First try works but after thread is too late than onResume and onCreate in activity

**3** should I have to make thread more fast? or use flags or something make onCreate and onResume works after thread works end? or does my code have problems?

This is my activity which show data from server

```
public class ServerListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static ArrayList<ServerListItem> serverListItemArrayList;
public static ArrayList<ServerListItem> scrollEventServerListItemList;
public TextView serverListInfoTextView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private boolean lockListView; 
private boolean isThisLastItemVisibleFlag;
private ServerListViewAdapter serverListViewAdapter;
private int currentPageNum;
public Handler msgHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lockListView = false; // scroll event
    currentPageNum = 0; // scroll event
    isThisLastItemVisibleFlag = false; // scroll event

    scrollEventServerListItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    serverListItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    msgHandler = new Handler();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ServerListManager serverListManager = new ServerListManager(msgHandler);
    serverListManager.getServerList();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_list);
    ImageButton turnBackBtn = findViewById(R.id.turn_back_btn);
    serverListInfoTextView = findViewById(R.id.server_list_Info);
    ListView serverListView = findViewById(R.id.server_list_view);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    serverListViewAdapter = new ServerListViewAdapter(scrollEventServerListItemList, R.layout.server_list_item, getApplicationContext());
    serverListView.setAdapter(serverListViewAdapter);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    serverListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
    System.out.println(serverListItemArrayList.size());
    setServerListInfo(serverListItemArrayList);
```

and this is my thread

```
public class ServerListManager {
private final static int SERVER_PROBLEM = 666;
private Handler handler;

public ServerListManager(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public void getServerList() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                URL url = new URL("my ip and blah balh");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (!"".equals(line)) {
                        stringBuffer.append(line);
                        Log.i("ServerListManager", stringBuffer.toString());
                    }
                    setServerListItem(stringBuffer.toString());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void setServerListItem(String dataFromServer) {
    Log.i("ServerListManager", "setServerListItem() works ");
    ArrayList<ServerListItem> serverListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObjectFirst = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(dataFromServer);
    if (!String.valueOf(jsonObjectFirst.get("status")).equals("\"200\"")) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = SERVER_PROBLEM;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
    } else {
        String serverListJsonVersion = String.valueOf(jsonObjectFirst.get("serverModelList"));
        JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) jsonParser.parse(serverListJsonVersion);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonArray) {
            ServerListItem serverListItem = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, ServerListItem.class);
            serverListItems.add(serverListItem);
        }
        ServerListActivity.serverListItemArrayList = serverListItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel thank you for leave comment :) i've never used that before ... i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `AsyncTask`

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        //can call progress bar here to show loading process
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //this method will be running on background thread 
        //so don't update UI from here
        //do your long running http tasks here,
        //you don't want to pass argument and you
        //can access the parent class' variable url over here

        // call your server data here
        serverListManager.getServerList();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        //Show the result obtained from doInBackground
        //this executed after doInBackground so after you get data from doInBackground
        //you can set your adapter here
    }

}
```

Then you can execute `AsyncTask` like this

```
new AsyncCaller().execute();
```